# Datamapper Many-To-Many relation

Tags: datamapper

Article has many authors, editors, translaters, etc. All of class Person.
Is it possible to generate join model? Or, in this case, solution is to create each join models manually.

```
class Article
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  property :published_date, Date
  property :status, Enum[ :pending, :accepted, :declined, :modified, :new ], :default => :new
  property :visible, Boolean, :default  => false

  timestamps :at

  has n, :authors, 'Person', :through => Resource
end


class Person

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  property :name, String
  property :about, Text
  property :gender, Enum[ :male, :female ]
  property :birthday, Date

  timestamps :at

  has n, :articles, :through => Resource
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it impossible. Only manual model creation.